# Best practice for storing TOKEN/password in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption

I’m working on a Java application that interacts with a REST API. To communicate with this API, I must use TOKEN, all these TOKEN are sensitive data and I cannot write in my code.

So I’m looking for a way like a configuration file to store the TOKEN and access it.

Currently, I made an XML file with all my TOKEN and I read, but I don’t think that’s the right way to do it.

I'm working with IDEA, JDK-17, Maven Project

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A java [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html)

Comment: Thats to long, I have multiple Object who eaxh has is hown token to acces to the api. And I need a conf file thats I can edit to add Object

Comment: It depends, you won't find a one best way to store passwords for every application. If you need a conf file then you can just encrypt these tokens with a password which you will need to type each time when starting application. You could generate new tokens each time with some 2 factor authentication etc. In general you shouldn't store sensitive data in application, you should have one token for each instance of application to access data not one for many applications. Like I said earlier it all depends on structure of application, distribution system, who will use that application etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I have observed so far, I believe this XML file is acting as a config file or something like that which manages environment variables at runtime. However, you need to be aware that any sensitive values should not be stored as plain text inside your repository, database, containers, etc.

A practical approach is to store sensitive values encrypted in a trustworthy and secure location and decrypting them just before deployment into production.

If you wish to store these tokens encrypted, you can use the github [encypted-secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) feature.  Then, before deployment, rebuild this XML using a CI pipeline, and let github handle decryption of values during the build time (See [this](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md) example).  As another example, you can use AWS [secret-manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html) to encrypt all values and then inject these values inside your container while deploying your docker container into ECS.

The advantages of this approach include preventing token leakage and providing easy key rotation by simply replacing values in Gtihub, AWS, etc and creating a new deployment.

Answer (score -1):

You can check Keycloak server:
https://www.keycloak.org/

Comment: I can't store sensitive data on other company product